# New to ANTLR: What is the difference between ANTLR and JavaParser

Tags: java, parsing, antlr

I am looking for a Java source code parser and came across JavaParser, however i noticed that there is a lack of documentation such that i can't really explore all the options of the library.

At the same time, i have come across another such library - ANTLR, may i know if anyone has experience working with ANTLR, whether ANTLR == JavaParser?

[JavaParser](http://code.google.com/p/javaparser/)
[ANTLR](http://antlr.org/)

Comment: _"whether ANTLR == JavaParser?"_: no they're not the same. JavaParser is a parser that parses Java code into an AST, and ANTLR is a parser generator, a.k.a. a [compiler-compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parser_generator).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ANTLR [grew from the old PCCTS](http://antlr.org/history.html) project, and has been under constant growth since 1988 or so. Java was a "recent" addition in the scale of ANTLR's lifetime.

JavaParser grew from [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/), which has always lived its life in Java-land.

Comment: Thanks. I got you, would you have any reference to good JavaParser documentation, or should i look at JavaCC for such documentation working with AST?

Comment: I've spent more time on ANTLR; I'll second [bn.'s recommendation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8380281/377270) of Terence Parr's [Language Implementation Patterns](http://pragprog.com/book/tpdsl/language-implementation-patterns), which gradually grows languages into requiring more and more powerful features in one of the best demonstrations of the differences between more simplistic and more powerful parsing techniques and what they make possible. I can't recommend the book highly enough.

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend reading Terence Parr's book: [Language Implementation Patterns](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/193435645X).

I won't rehash the book and his/ANTLR's website content here, but my understanding, or "take away" if you like, is that JavaParser, built on [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/) is considered a great tool, but is not as robust, nor does it have the user community and tooling (ANTLRWorks) that ANTLR does.  ANTLR is also a very powerful tool allowing you to create parser generators, specifically LL(*) recursive decent parsers and others as well.

Also ANTLR is also [licensed](http://www.antlr.org/license.html) under BSD, while JavaParser falls under the GNU Lesser GPL [license](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/lgpl.html).

My preference would be ANTLR.